# How do I checkout a single file?

Tags: file, cvs, vcs-checkout

I would like to checkout `file1` from CVS repository to the current directory.

File1's path is: `/opt/application/CVS_REPOSITORY/project/lib/source/file1`

How do I do it?

First I set:

```
setenv CVSROOT /opt/application/CVS_REPOSITORY
```

Then what should I do?

```
cvs co -r . /lib/source/file1 ??
```

Or

```
cvs co -r . project/lib/source/file1  ??
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `cvs co project/lib/source/file1`

Comment: Thanks. but now when I try to commit everything, I get "Up-to-date check failed for lib/source/file1" error. What should I do next?

Comment: Someone else has committed changes to the file since you checked it out. You need to do a `cvs update`.

Answer (score 5):

I had to use "cvs update *filename*" to pull single file from cvs module. Run this command in the module local workspace.

Comment: Please elaborate on the answer. Do you have a link to this information?